# How do I simplify a repetitive if/elif statment in Python?

Tags: python

I have been set the following task:

> Your friend works for an antique book shop that sells books between
> 1800 and 1950 and wants to quickly categorise books by the century and
> decade that they were written.
>
> Write a program that takes a year (e.g. 1872) and outputs the century
> and decade (e.g. "Nineteenth Century, Seventies")

My solution works but is way too bulky:

```
age_of_book = int(input ('What year was the book written?'))

if age_of_book >= 1800 and age_of_book <= 1809:
    print ('This book was written in the Ninteenth century, Noughties')
elif age_of_book >= 1810 and age_of_book <= 1819:
    print('This book was written in the Ninteenth century, Tens')
elif age_of_book >= 1820 and age_of_book <= 1829:
    print('This book was written in the Ninteenth century, Twenties')

# etc.
```

Comment: Split the problem into **two parts** - `18` -> "Nineteenth century" and `72` -> "seventies". Maybe you'll note as you do so that one of the digits isn't really helping much...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be smarter about it, in the event that you might get books from the 3rd century to the 22nd (in the future) and don't want to write all those ifs, I would do something like:

```py
suffix_dict = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
def get_suffix(n: int):
    if n%100 in [11, 12, 13]:
        return 'th'
    return suffix_dict.get(n%10, 'th')

def stringify_year(year: int):
    century = year//100+1
    century_suffix = get_suffix(century)
    decade = year%100//10*10
    return f"Published in the {century}{century_suffix} century, in the {decade:>02}'s"

>>> stringify_year(1776)
Out: "Published in the 18th century, in the 70's"
```

This doesn't account for books written BCE, however, so you may want to modify...

I just noticed @Osamodas's answer (posted while I was writing this), which does a similar thing -- if you really want words "nineteenth" rather than numbers "19th", maybe combine these two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get rid of the if , you could create a dictionnary or an array to represent each decades by a string. Then you just remove the part that is over 100 with a modulo, you divided by 10 and you get the decade. I tried to implement it and it give something like this.

```py
decades = {
    0: "Noughties",
    1: "Tens",
    2: "Twenties",
    3: "Thirties",
    4: "Forties",
    5: "Fifties",
    6: "Sixties",
    7: "Seventies",
    8: "Eighties",
    9: "Nineties"
}

age_of_book = int(input('What year was the book written?'))


century = "Nineteenth Century"
decade = age_of_book % 100 // 10
decade_name = decades.get(decade, "")
print(f"This book was written in the {century}, {decade_name}")
```

Note that you could also use an array like this just as well like this

```py
decades = [
    "Noughties",
    "Tens",
    "Twenties",
    "Thirties",
    "Forties",
    "Fifties",
    "Sixties",
    "Seventies",
    "Eighties",
    "Nineties"
]

age_of_book = int(input('What year was the book written?'))

century = "Nineteenth Century"
decade = age_of_book % 100 // 10
decade_name = decades[decade]
print(f"This book was written in the {century}, {decade_name}")
```

If you are really motivated you could even do the same for centuries.